# Redirect all .jpg links, replacing a part of url htaccess but still display images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I want to redirect all .jpg (when the image link is clicked on **another** website, or coming from another website) link to a page where the image is embeded.
Example:

```
www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/26/blue-pen.jpg
```

to

```
www.example.com/wp-content/show-image.php?path=www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/26/blue-pen.jpg
```

I tried two codes, but they are incomplete for me. This one will not copy the full url of the image, even tho I tried adding `$1` at the end:

```
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?www.example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.jpg$ /wp-content/show-image.php?path= [L,R=302.NC]
```

and the one below does the work, but images will not show on my website at all, when using them like `<img src="www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/26/blue-pen.jpg"/>`

I need that to work and display the image on my website, and if possible allow it on other websites as well.

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/wp-content/show-image.php?path=http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,R=302.NC]
```

I know it can be done, but I don't know how. What should I modify?

Comment: `R=302.NC`? flags are separated by `,`, not `.`, so you're trying to redirect with a status code of `302.NC`

Comment: yes, ok thanks, but that will not change the problem with not working as I want it to